# How to find determinant of the following $3\times 3$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

How to find the determinant of the following block matrix?

$$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda I-A & -A &-J\\
-A& \lambda I & 0\\
-J& 0 & \lambda I\end{pmatrix}$$

where $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix and $\lambda$ is a scalar.
$J$ is a square matrix of order $n$.

I tried using row and column operations like using $R_1\to R_1+R_2$ but I am not getting anything fruitful.
What is the way out? Is there any special trick to do this?

Comment: Apparently, $J$ is typically used to denote a matrix with all entries equal to 1... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones

Comment: We don't know what? Try looking again at $n=1,2,3$. Then it becomes rather obvious.

Comment: (i) I'd divide the 2nd and 3rd blocks of rows by $\lambda$ and mutiply the first block of columns by $\lambda$ and keep track of the power of $\lambda$ which I've not yet used. (ii) I'd add $A$ times the 2nd block of rows to the first block of rows (iii) I'd add $J$ times the 3rd block of rows to the first block of rows (iii) I'd now have the determinant of  a combination of $I, A, A^2, J$. Or maybe look at Matrix Determinant Lemma?

Comment: You may use [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) to simplify the determinant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Schur complement formula for the determinant of a block matrix,$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} X & Y\\
Z& W\end{pmatrix} = \det W \det(X- Y W^{-1} Z),$$
with the lower right $2n\times 2n$ block to be $W$ as it's simple to invert, I find that
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} \lambda I-A & -A &-J\\
-A& \lambda I & 0\\
-J& 0 & \lambda I\end{pmatrix} = \lambda^n \det (\lambda^2 I - \lambda A - A^2 - J^2).$$

Edit;
I applied the determinant formula differently and found $$\det \begin{pmatrix} \lambda I-A & -A &-J\\
-A& \lambda I & 0\\
-J& 0 & \lambda I\end{pmatrix} = \frac{\det(J^2)\det (2\lambda^2 I -  2A^2 - \lambda A)}{\det(\lambda I -A)},$$ which you might prefer depending on your application, @Math_Freak